# Can't get TP-Link TL-WN823N running on RPI4B

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-4

WIfi dongle TP-Link TL-WN823N will be not automatically recognized on RPI4B.
I also can't find any matching drivers to install it manually.

How can I fix it to get it running?

Please help, I am a newbie.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: stop searching for RPi drivers and start searching for Linux drivers

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=198015 - which version of that dongle do you have? what's the output of `lsusb`?

Comment: dongle is listed on lsusb but no wlan1

Comment: I already tried the mentioned manual from rotum entry mentioned in your comment but now it is listed on lsusb but still no wlan1 aviailable. Only on-board wlan0


 
`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0109 TP-Link TL WN823N RTL8192EU
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:2b4a HP, Inc Business Slim Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:094a HP, Inc Optical Mouse [672662-001]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Comment: `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no`

Answer (score 0):

First link in a Google search it suggested top of the list after pasting the model of dongle into the search box lead to this on Ask Ubuntu. The detailed instructions are there for Debian too. Who knows if the source builds on arm.

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=tp-link+tl-wn823n+ubuntu

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211157/how-do-i-get-a-tp-link-tl-wn823n-v3-wireless-adapter-working

Comment: Why are you posting links about ubuntu? Raspbian has nothing to do with Ubuntu

Comment: It is a procedure designed for any operating system, including Debian, which the Pi OS is based on. A driver needing compiled is the same procedure on all those operating systems. That is why it is posted it does the job he needs to get it done and working. Which you would know if you had read the material provided.

Comment: erm, sure, but why did you link to a page that uses D-link drivers for a tp-link, and the drivers come from a github that claims to be a mirror of *something* with no knowledge of what the code does :p sorry, but https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=198015 is more trustworthy in my opinion :p

Comment: From the page in the section for building it.  "
If you have internet access by any other means (wired or through USB tethering), you can installed the RTL8192EU drivers for your TP-LINK TL-WN823N wireless adapter from Mange's GitHub repo. Here are the steps as described on the GitHub page:"